# Geometric reasoning and triangular coordinates

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

The following is from a book:
[image]

I do not understand the sentence "... the point $(t_1, t_2, t_3)$ can be plotted by plotting $(t_1 = t_3, t_2 = t_3)$...", what is meant by the point $(t_1 = t_3, t_2 = t_3)$? How it is written it is $(t_3, t_3)$, but I do not think that every point $(t_1, t_2, t_3)$ could not be indentified with $(t_3, t_3)$?

EDIT: On next page in the book, see comments on Steven Taschuk's answer:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It says "$(t_1-t_3,t_2-t_3)$".  (They're setting $a=-t_3$ in the previous sentence.)

Comment: Perhaps you could also describe in more detail what it meant by $(t_1-t_3,t_2-t_3)$ giving a point on the plane.

Comment: If I understand you right they identify the point $(t_1 - t_3, t_2 - t_3)$ in the plane with the point $(t_1 - t_3, t_2 - t_3, 0)$ which gets projected to the same point as $(t_1, t_2, t_3)$, but with reference to what coordinate system he plots $(t_1 - t_3, t_2 - t_3)$?, where is the x-axix and where the y-axis?

Comment: The coordinate axes are the arrows labelled "$t_1$" and "$t_2$" in the picture.  In 3-space these were the usual coordinate axes; now they have been projected onto a plane in our vision, and what we see is what is shown in the figure (which is $2$-dimensional).

Comment: (Note that $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$, labelled in the picture, are mapped to $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$, the fundamental vectors of the coordinate system being described.)

Comment: But this interpretation does not match with the picture on the next page of the book, where the triangle with vertices $(3,-1,2), (4,2,6)$ and $(-2,4,2)$ is drawn. For example consider the point $(4,2,6) = (-2,-4,0)$, If I project it perpendicular on the $t_1$-axis it goes somewhere near the point $(0,0)$, but not $(-2,0)$?

Comment: The coordinate system is oblique, not perpendicular; project parallel to the $t_2$ axis.